# UK visa in the USA , question about the Biometric appointment?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, paperwork, applications

From those who went to a Biometrics appointment for the UK visa in the USA.

What should you bring to the USCIS biometrics appointment?

Is bringing and handing USCIS the application print out necessary?

Will the USCIS(An United States agency) keep a copy of my application or is it a special paper customized for the appointment that I should give to the USCIS biometrics center?

I am very hazy on the details . I would really appreciate if those of you who went through this process could assist me . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you visit the Application Support Centre for your biometrics appointment, you should take your current passport, a print out of your application form and a copy of your biometric confirmation receipt. You can print your receipt when you apply online.

Detailed guidance on the process is available here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa

Comment: Thank you for replying but I have already read what s on the GOV UK website . I need someone's experience regarding this issue who did the process and can assist me with the question " Does the USCIS keep a copy of my UK visa application ??

Comment: @Hamid Nazaki Do you mean do they keep a paper copy? It would be safe to assume they keep your application details in a database. The instructions on the website state quite clearly that you need to take a print out of your application ie one hard copy. If you want a copy for your records, print 2 or save a soft copy.

Comment: I mean does the USCIS which is a United States Government agency get to have a copy of my UK visa application ? My question is about privacy and record keeping . what  is the USCIS role in the process ? Do they just get my details (name , birth date ...) or do they copy my application which is for UK visa ?